# What buffer size should be chosen for serial communication of sensor readings?

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, buffer

I have an arduino board that is connected to a sensor. From Arduino IDE serial monitor, I see the readings are mostly 160, 150, etc. Arduino has a 10 bit ADC, so I assume the readings range from 0 to 1024.

I want to fetch that readings to my computer so that I can do further processing. It must be done this way up to this point. Now, I wrote a c++ program to read serial port buffer with Windows APIs (DCB). The transfer speed of the serial ports are set to 115200 on both the Arduino IDE and the c++ program.

I will describe my problem first: Since I want to send the readings to my computer, I expect the data looks like the following:

```
124
154
342
232
...
```

But now it looks like

```
321
43
5
2
123
...
```

As shown, the data are concatenated. I knew it because I tried to display them with `[]`, and the data are truly messed up.

The section of the code that is doing the serial port reading on the computer is as here:

```
// Read
int n = 10;
char szBuff[10 + 1] = {0};
DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 200; i++){
    {
        if(!ReadFile(hSerial, szBuff, n, &dwBytesRead, NULL)){
            //error occurred. Report to user.
            printf("Cannot read.\n");
        }
        else{
            printf("%s\n" , szBuff);
        }
    }
}
```

The Arduino code that's doing the serial port sending is:

```
char buffer [10] = { 0 };
int analogIn = 0;
int A0_val = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop() {
    A0_val = analogRead(analogIn);
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", A0_val);
    Serial.println(buffer);
}
```

I suspect that the messing up of the data is caused by different size of the buffer used to transmit and receive data in the serial port. What is the good suggestion for the size of the buffer and even better method to guarantee the successful transmission of valid data?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reciever code cannot assume a single read from the serial port will yield a complete line (i.e. the 2 or 3 digits followed by a '\n' that the arduino continuously sends).

It is up to the receiver to synthetize complete lines of text on reception, and only then try to use them as meaningful numbers.

Since the serial interface is extremely slow compared with your average PC computing power, there is little point in reading more than one character at a time: literally millions of CPU cycles will be spent waiting for the next character, so you really don't need to react fast to the arduino input.

Since in that particular case it will not hinder performances in the slightest, I find it more convenient to read one character at a time. That will save you the hassle of moving bits of strings around. At least it makes writing an educational example easier.

```
// return the next value received from the arduino as an integer
int read_arduino (HANDLE hserial)
{
    char buffer[4];       // any value longer than 3 digits must come 
                          // from a faulty transmission
                          // the 4th caracter is used for a terminating '\0'
    size_t buf_index = 0; // storage position of received characters
    for (;;)
    {
        char c; // read one byte at a time

        if (!ReadFile(
            hSerial,
            &c,   // 1 byte buffer
            1,    // of length 1 
            NULL, // we will read exactly one byte or die trying,
                  // so length checking is pointless
            NULL)){
            /*
             * This error means something is wrong with serial port config,
             * and I assume your port configuration is hard-coded, 
             * so the code won't work unless you modify and recompile it.
             * No point in keeping the progam running, then.
             */
            fprintf (stderr, "Dang! Messed up the serial port config AGAIN!");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else // our read succeded. That's a start.
        {
            if (c == '\n') // we're done receiving a complete value
            {
                int result; // the decoded value we might return

                // check for buffer overflow
                if (buf_index == sizeof (buffer))
                {
                    // warn the user and discard the input
                    fprintf (stderr,
                        "Too many characters received, input flushed\n");
                }
                else // valid number of characters received
                {
                    // add a string terminator to the buffer
                    buffer[buf_index] = '\0';

                    // convert to integer
                    result = atoi (buffer);

                    if (result == 0)
                    {
/*
 * assuming 0 is not a legit value returned by the arduino, this means the
 * string contained something else than digits. It could happen in case
 * of electricval problems on the line, typically if you plug/unplug the cable
 * while the arduino is sending (or Mr Fluffy is busy gnawing at it).
 */
                        fprintf (stderr, "Wrong value received: '%s'\n", buffer);
                    }
                    else // valid value decoded
                    {
                        // at last, return the coveted value
                        return res; // <-- this is the only exit point
                    }
                }

                // reset buffer index to prepare receiving the next line
                buf_index = 0;
            }
            else // character other than '\n' received
            {
                // store it as long as our buffer does not overflow
                if (buf_index < sizeof (buffer))
                {
                    buffer[buf_index++] = c;
/*
 * if, for some reason, we receive more than the expected max number of
 * characters, the input will be discarded until the next '\n' allow us
 * to re-synchronize.
 */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CAVEAT: this is just code off the top of my head. I might have left a few typos here and there, so don't expect it to run or even compile out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of basic problems here. First, it is unlikely that the PC can reliably keep up with 115,200 baud data if you only read 10 bytes at a time with ReadFile.  Try a slower baud rate and/or change the buffer size and number of bytes per read to something that will get around 20 milliseconds of data, or more.

Second, after you read some data put a nul at the end of it

```
 szBuf[dwBytesRead] = 0;
```

before you pass it to printf or any other C string code.

Comment: OP initializes the whole buffer with {0}. No problem with nulls at the end, even if he reads the full 10 bytes.

Comment: Does a char type buffer of size 10 means 10 bytes of data?

Comment: @poljpocket: The current code only initializes szBuff to nulls one time -- if one of the 200 ReadFile calls somehow gets fewer than 10 bytes (actually, fewer than read into szBuff in a previous iteration), then an earlier read's final bytes will appear appended to the end of the later, shorter read's version of the buffer.

Comment: @christopher-oicles I didn't see that, sorry